# Can anyone explain why my question is closed as "Needs more focus"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

I posted a [question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/45307/no-pain-doesnt-mean-that-workout-isnt-effective-how-about-the-other-way-aroun) about the relation between pain and the effectiveness of workout. And later, I found that it was closed, and the reason is "Needs more focus".

However, I don't agree with the closure, so I'm writing this post in meta to discuss this issue. This is the [link](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/45307/no-pain-doesnt-mean-that-workout-isnt-effective-how-about-the-other-way-aroun) of the original version. And since it's short, I'll also post it here:

> I've seen a website on this site (Physical Fitness StackExchange), that after a workout, no pain to the muscle you're training doesn't mean that the workout isn't effective. However, if the muscle is painful, does it mean that your workout is effective? By "muscle is painful" I'm not talking about sports injury due to incorrect posture or something.

According to an article from the [Help Center](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help), [What does it mean if a question is "closed"](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions):

> - **Needs more focus** - If your question has many valid answers (but no way to determine which, if any, are correct), then it probably needs to be more focused to be successful in our format.
>
> > This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.
>
> This can often be fixed by breaking the post into multiple questions, or by focusing on a specific part of the problem.

First, my question doesn't has many valid answers (Only yes / no, and maybe an explanation). Secondly, there are no multiple questions in my post! There's only one question, with only one question mark in the whole text.

So my question is, why is my question closed? Especially why the reason is "needs more focus"? I clearly only have one question per post!

Comment: For your information, *"Needs Focus"* was just the final 2:1 closure reason and the initial flag was for *"Needs Details or Clarity"*. Needs focus was misleading but needing additional clarity would be the appropriate close flag. Clarity was added, and the question re-opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disagree with the closure, but I think the problem was that the title is confusing due to the fact that it contained four negatives, which I've bolded below.

"**No** pain **doesn't** mean that workout **isn't** effective. How about **the other way around**?"

A less confusing way to write this question would be:

"Does the presence of muscle soreness necessarily mean that the workout that caused it must have been effective?"

The question body could also be changed to:

"I've seen answers on this site<sup>[[1](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15826/doms-good-or-bad), [2](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/27891/what-are-the-implications-of-diminishing-levels-of-soreness-in-delayed-onset-mus), [3]](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19155/why-do-my-muscles-ache-the-day-after-i-lift-how-come-not-asap-after-my-workout/19157#19157)</sup> stating that muscle soreness occurring after a workout is not needed in order for the workout to be effective, where 'effective' means causing a strength increase or muscle growth. So it is possible for a workout to be effective without causing muscle soreness. However, what about the other way around? Can a workout cause muscle soreness without being effective?"

Comment: Great, thanks for your explanation. If you think that it's ok, it'll probably be reopened soon. By the way, can you allow me to use the title you mentioned in your answer?

Comment: @Eden0516 Yes, you are welcome to use any part of my suggestions in your question.

Comment: Thanks, that's very kind of you :)

Comment: Thank you for helping to clarify the question, David!